# Tvheadend on Android DVB-S2 TV Box(AML8726-MX)

Tags: android-tv

I have Android DVB-S2 TV Box 
CPU: Amlogic AML8726-MX 
TV-Tuner: AVL6211

I need to install Tvheadend server to the device. To play video in the browser (on the same device) via RTP (or nativ android app - VideoView).

I found Tvheadend compiled under Android. It starts, but the TV tuner was not recognized correctly.

Can someone have a successful experience in installing this software?

If you have experience in writing android applications for such hardware, please tell me where to start!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should install some Linux OS like Ubuntu. Tvheadend server works only in Linux.
There is no other way.